# How to add a grid in Angular js with other existing angular component

Tags: angular, angularjs

I am trying to add a grid in angular js page. I have written the below script for it but it is not populating the data in the grid.

[image: How it looks now]

Below is the code written. Some of the things are coming up well but grid is not coming up with the sample data. What could be the reason for this.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

 <h1>Order Dashboard</h1>
<div >
         <p><label for="CurrentDate">Current Date:</label><input type = "date" ng-model = "name">
        <label for="PreviousDate">Previous Date:</label><input type = "date" ng-model = "name"></p>
        </div>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        <p>{{item.profName}}
        <select ng-options="profVals for profVals in item.profVals" ng-model="item.selected"></select>
    </div>
</div>

<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="app.grid as ctrl" class="container text-center">
         <h4>Grid with Header Filters Demo</h4>

        <table class="table table-condense">
            <caption>Grid Test</caption>
            <thead>
                <tr class="bg-primary">
                    <th>Year</th>
                    <th>Make</th>
                    <th>Model</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input class="form-control" ng-model="ctrl.search.year" ng-change="ctrl.filter()" type="text">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input class="form-control" ng-model="ctrl.search.make" ng-change="ctrl.filter()" type="text">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input class="form-control" ng-model="ctrl.search.model" ng-change="ctrl.filter()" type="text">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="itemp in ctrl.filteredList">
                    <td>{{item.year}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.make}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.model}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr class="bg-info">
                    <td colspan="3"></td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope',

function ($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{
        profName: "Order Type",
        profEdit: true,
        profVals: ["First", "Second", "Third"]
    }, {
        profName: "Order Channel",
        profEdit: true,
        profVals: ["First", "Second", "Third"]
    }];
}]);

var appName = 'app';
var app = angular.module(appName, ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('app.grid', ['$scope', '$filter', gridCtrl]);


function gridCtrl($scope, $filter) {
    var ctrl = this;

    ctrl.items = [{
        year: 1999,
        make: 'Nissan',
        model: 'Altima'
    }, {
        year: 1999,
        make: 'Nissan',
        model: 'Cube'
    }, {
        year: 2011,
        make: 'Nissan',
        model: 'Rogue'
    }, {
        year: 2011,
        make: 'Nissan',
        model: 'xTerra'
    }, {
        year: 2012,
        make: 'Nissan',
        model: 'Altima'
    }, {
        year: 2012,
        make: 'Nissan',
        model: 'Cube'
    }, {
        year: 2012,
        make: 'Nissan',
        model: 'Rogue'
    }, {
        year: 2012,
        make: 'Nissan',
        model: 'xTerra'
    }, {
        year: 1999,
        make: 'Toyota',
        model: 'Corolla'
    }, {
        year: 1999,
        make: 'Toyota',
        model: 'Yaris'
    }, {
        year: 2012,
        make: 'Toyota',
        model: 'Camry'
    }, {
        year: 2012,
        make: 'Toyota',
        model: 'Rav4'
    }, {
        year: 2013,
        make: 'Toyota',
        model: 'Corolla'
    }, {
        year: 2014,
        make: 'Toyota',
        model: 'Yaris'
    }, {
        year: 2014,
        make: 'Toyota',
        model: 'Camry'
    }, {
        year: 2014,
        make: 'Toyota',
        model: 'Rav4'
    }];

    ctrl.filteredList = ctrl.items;
    ctrl.search = {};

    ctrl.filter = function () {
        this.filteredList = $filter('filter')(ctrl.items, ctrl.search);
    }

}
</script>

 </body>
</html>
```